# Django paths, developing in windows, deploying on linux

Tags: django, path

I'm developing Django apps on my local windows machine then deploying to a hosted linux server. The format for paths is different between the two and manually replacing before deployment is consuming more time than it should. I could code based on a variable in my settings file and if statements but I was wondering if anyone had best practices for this scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Django book suggests using `os.path.join` (and to use slashes instead of backslashes on Windows):

```
import os.path

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates').replace('\\','/'),
)
```

I think this is the best solution as you can easily create relative paths like that. If you have multiple relative paths, a helper function will shorten the code:

```
def fromRelativePath(*relativeComponents):
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), *relativeComponents).replace("\\","/")
```

If you need absolute paths, you should use an environment variable (with `os.environ["MY_APP_PATH"]`) in combination with `os.path.join`.

Comment: This is the best answer, you can use slashes in windows and linux.  Backslashes were the biggest issue I was having.

Comment: You might want to use `posixpath.join()` instead of `os.path.join().replace()` -- it makes your intent clear: you want a POSIX-style path regardless of your OS.

Comment: @CraigTrader: it's a nice idea to use `posixpath.join()`, but that won't remove backslashes that are already in the path components being joined (e.g., from `os.path.dirname(__file__)`.

Answer (score 2):

We have a situation very similar to yours, and we've been using different paths in settings, basing on `sys.platform`.
Something like this:

```
import os, sys
DEVELOPMENT_MODE = sys.platform == 'win32'
if DEVELOPMENT_MODE:
    HOME_DIR = 'c:\\django-root\\'
else:
    HOME_DIR = '/home/django-root/'
```

It works quite OK - assumed all development is being done on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
import os.path

BASE_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

at the top of your settings file, and then use `BASE_PATH` everywhere you want to use a path relative to your Django project.

For example:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_PATH, 'media')
```

(You need to use os.path.join(), instead of simply writing something like `MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_PATH+'/media'`, because Unix joins directories using '/', while windows prefers '\')

Answer (score 0):

in your **settings.py** add the following lines

```
import os.path

SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))  
head, tail = os.path.split(SETTINGS_PATH)

#add some directories to the path
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.join(head, "apps"))
#do what you want with SETTINGS_PATH
```